# What container to store unique values with no operator< defined

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

I need to store unique objects in a container. The object provides a `operator==` and `operator!=` (`operator<` nor `operator>`).

I can't use `std::set`, as it requires a `operator<`.
I can't use `std::unordered_set` as it requires a hash function and I have none. Let's say I can't write one considering my object type (or I'm lazy).

Am I really forced to use a `std::vector` and make sure myself that items does not get duplicated in the container (using `std::find` which uses `operator==`)?

Is there really no container that could be used to store unique items only using the `operator==`?

Comment: `std::unordered_set` does not require `operator<`

Comment: [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) does not require a comparison operator. That's the point of an "unordered" data structure

Comment: As above. The only thing is to provide an hash function for the unique object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767234/what-container-to-store-unique-values --- DUPLICATE QUESTION

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural: Actually, no, as it doesn't mention `operator<` at all.

Comment: @Slava: True, my mistake, Edited the post. I'd like a container that would not require more code to be written. `operator==` should be enough to make a container store unique unordered values.

Comment: Then you're stuck with O(N) singularity check.

Comment: Use `std::set`. After reading the docs.

Comment: The problem with using `operator==` only is that you can only compare one object to another. Given the result of `operator==` there's no way of knowing how it compares to other objects without comparing it with those as well. With `operator<` you have ordering in the container and can already eliminate half (on average) of the other objects.

Comment: I'm not concerned about performance here. As my only alternative right now is to use `std::vector` and `std::find`.

Comment: @Kevin: Using `operator==` isn't really a "problem". It works perfecly when using `std::find` to check if an element is not already in a `std::vector` before pushing it to guarantee there is no duplicate in the container.

Comment: @jpo38: that's not an alternative, if those are your requirements, that's the *solution*.

Comment: As `std::find` requires input iterator you can use with pretty much any container, why do you think it works only with `std::vector`?

Comment: Can you write a custom comparison predicate? Sometimes you can

Comment: @Slava: lack of operator< and hashing function rules out most of the containers.

Comment: @milleniumbug: I'm not owning the library providing the objects. It would not be that easy.

Comment: @jpo38 and these objects don't have any externally visible state you can use for a consistent ordering or hash calculation? Wow, that's no fun.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath most? `std::find` will work on any container. Luck of hash or `operator<` will eliminate only `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`, so any other like `std::list` `std::deque` `std::forward_list` will work.

Comment: @Slava: I mean.. it eliminates the *good* choices. `vector` is the best choice left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's indeed no standard container, and that's because it would be inefficient. `O(N)`, to be precise - exactly the brute force search you imagine.

Both `std::set<T>` and `std::unordered_set<T>` avoid a brute-force search by taking advantage of a non-trivial property of T. Lacking either property, any of the existing N members of a container could be equal to a potential new value V, and you must therefore compare all N members using `operator==` repeatedly.

Comment: Do you mean that the standard will not develop, let's call it, a "unique_vector" container only because it won't be efficient. It's true STL provides effective code but it also provides code to make developers life easier...no?

Comment: @jpo38: Yes, that's indeed the case. Same reason as why `std::list` doesn't have an O(N) `operator[ ]`; it could be implemented but wouldn't be fast.

Comment: It wouldn't provide a unique_vector because `std::unordered_set` is already provided which is more efficient. If you can write an `operator==` it's a safe assumption that you can write a hash function in most cases.

Comment: @Kevin: That's not a safe assumption, actually. Try writing a hash function that hashes `std::vector<std::string>`, for instance. Keep in mind that strings can contain any `char` including `\0` and a vector can contain empty strings. Equality is trivial, in comparison.

Comment: @MSalters: what's the problem there?

Comment: @jpo38 they cannot create containers for every possible case. Your case is not usual and I doubt there is a value for everybody to have such container.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Just try to make sure that `{"ab"}, {"a","b"}, {"a","", "b"}, {"a","b", ""}` etcetera all get different hashes. Of course, you can trivially hash everything to `1`, but then you get an O(N) collection. (Which to be honest would work in this particular case)

Comment: @MSalters: Why on earth would they get the same hashes? You're imagining a problem there.

Comment: @MSalters there's difference between producing occasional collision (like {"a","b"} having same hash as {"a","b", ""}), and between `return 1;` hash function. If you know your data well, you can usually produce reasonably spread hash even without processing all the content, maybe even summing lengths of strings may be enough for some applications.

Comment: Surely adding `""` changes the hash (I'm not saying *always*, just with *sane* hashing functions).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath if you made the hash by iterating over the vector and the vector's strings it would be examining the characters "ab" each time. Of course, if you knew that it would be storing such things, you'd at least factor in string ends to the hash, or string numbers and lengths...

Comment: @jaggedSpire: exactly.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think what MSalters is trying to say is it's difficult to get a good general-purpose hash for a vector of strings, because you probably want to use only a subset of the information available to keep the hash fast, but which subset will provide the lowest collision rate would vary heavily by the characteristics of the strings in the vector. While in many cases using each character would generate fewer collisions than simply using the length of each string (at the price of a slow hash), in his example case it would be worse.

Answer (score 2):

"Let's say I can't write a hash function considering my object type (or I'm lazy)."

Well, you're lazy, but I'll write one for you anyway : `template<typename T> size_t degenerate_hash(T) { return 0; }`.

Of course, this means you get O(N) performance because every value collides with every other value, but that was the best possible outcome anyway.

Comment: That's definitely a nice solution! Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::vector` and before you `std::vector::push_back` or `std::vector::insert` use first `std::find` to check whether the element already exists in the vector.

Or at the end of all insertions use `std::unique` in combination with `std::vector::erase` to remove duplicates.

Comment: That's what I'm actually doing right now. Was just surprised the STL did not provide a container doing this autmatically...I'll have to keep this solution then! Thanks.

Comment: @jpo38 I don't see any reason why STL should support a data structure like this, since there's `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` for it. IMHO it's not a big deal to provide a `operator<` for your stuff .

Comment: `std::unique` will only work if the equivalent elements are consecutive, right?